# Best read performance when every query is known, and the data doesn't change

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, postgis, gist-index

I'm trying to maximise performance on an underpowered PostGIS server - 1 core, 4 CPUs. The data (OpenStreetMap) will be infrequently (monthly?) loaded, and never changes otherwise. Each of the 30 or so queries for the map rendering is static, except that the bounding box for each tile changes.

Is this a common situation? What's the best approach? For example:

1. Create an index exactly matching each query:

   ```
   CREATE index roads_high_idx 
    ON planet_osm_line
   USING gist(way)
   WHERE (highway IS NOT NULL OR railway IS NOT NULL)
     AND (tunnel IS NULL OR tunnel = 'no')
     AND (bridge IS NULL OR bridge = 'no');
   ```
2. Pre-load all the queries into other tables:

   ```
   SELECT [columns]
   INTO roads_high
   FROM planet_osm_line;
   CREATE index roads_high_idx 
    ON planet_osm_line
   WHERE (highway IS NOT NULL OR railway IS NOT NULL)
     AND (tunnel IS NULL OR tunnel = 'no')
     AND (bridge IS NULL OR bridge = 'no')
   ORDER BY ...;
   ```
3. Some smarter approach, where Postgres figures this out implicitly?

Although all the queries are known, they're buried in an XML project file, so it's not quite trivial to extract them all.

Comment: Häh? Normally you may have 1 CPU, 4 cores. But having more cpu's than cores - what did you do? Hit a core with a hammer and distribute the parts into multiple CPU slots?

Comment: Do you already *have*  a performance problem? If so you should post the specific details. If not, you should properly index and then see how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, here are a few things to do, in no particular order.

- `VACUUM FREEZE`
- `ANALYZE`
- Add the indexes that you think are going to help.
- Execute as many queries as you can.
- Look at `pg_stat_user_indexes` to see which queries are being used.
- Look at the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` plan for each query.
- Review https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions
- Review https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server
- Post follow-ups with server specs and questions to SO or the Postgresql mailing lists (most of the core developers answer questions in the pg lists).

It will likely be an iterative process, so don't expect to get it right in the first go.

Comment: I also strongly suggest creating the indexes only *after* the data load. It'll not only make the data load way faster, but it'll produce more compact and sensible indexes.